# Check if each string from array is contained by another string array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Sorry I'am new on Ruby (just a Java programmer), I have two string arrays:

- Array with file paths.
- Array with patterns (can be a path or a file)

I need to check each patter over each "file path". I do with this way:

```
@flag = false
["aa/bb/cc/file1.txt","aa/bb/cc/file2.txt","aa/bb/dd/file3.txt"].each do |source|
  ["bb/cc/","zz/xx/ee"].each do |to_check|
    if source.include?(to_check)
      @flag = true
    end
  end 
end
puts @flag
```

This code is ok, prints "**true**" because "bb/cc" is in source.

I have seen several posts but can not find a better way. I'm sure there should be functions that allow me to do this in fewer lines. 
Is this is possible?

Comment: Have you read the docs for Ruby's Enumerable? Check out `Enumerable#any?`.

Comment: @dodecaphonic Thanks for help me. I will check Ruby's enumerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @dodecaphonic use `Enumerable#any?`. Something like this:

```
paths.any? { |s| patterns.any? { |p| s[p] } }
```

where `paths` and `patterns` are arrays as defined by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

While that will work, that's going to have geometric scaling problems, that is it has to do N*M tests for a list of N files versus M patterns. You can optimize this a little:

```
files = ["aa/bb/cc/file1.txt","aa/bb/cc/file2.txt","aa/bb/dd/file3.txt"]

# Create a pattern that matches all desired substrings
pattern = Regexp.union(["bb/cc/","zz/xx/ee"])

# Test until one of them hits, returns true if any matches, false otherwise
files.any? do |file|
  file.match(pattern)
end
```

You can wrap that up in a method if you want. Keep in mind that if the pattern list doesn't change you might want to create that once and keep it around instead of constantly re-generating it.

Comment: Doesn't the regex engine have to perform up to M tests when evaluating `file.match(pattern)` for up to N files?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The regular expression itself runs in fairly short amounts of time, and for something trivial like this it's basically O(N).